# python install on machine with no internet but has basic python interpreter

Tags: python, installation, package, offline

following is my question/problem:

1. I am have installed python on two machine, machine A with internet ,machine B without internet.
2. I need to install packages(say for example pillow package) on machine B
3. I tried :pip download pillow ,on machine a in folder.
4. It created wheel file which does not work on machine B (some packages download as zip which can be installed on machine B ,but not one with wheel file.
5. I am trying route of virtual env.
6. On machine A I am doing :1. C:\pro1> myenv\scripts\activate
7. myenv C:\vi\pro1> pip install pillow
8. Taking the whole folder to machine B .
9. Assuming it should work as the package is in virtual env folder ,but it doesn't . :(

How can I make pillow package work on offline machine ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why doesn't the wheel file work on machine B?  Do you get errors when you try to use it?

Comment: yes sir..i get error when I use :  "pip install piliow**.whl", from command line of that folder.Thx Vi

Comment: It would be much more helpful to **show** the error, instead of just telling us you got an error...

Comment: cant copy the image, copying the command line text and paste ..here you go  sir..:C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\pkgs2xfer>pip install Pillow-8.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: Pillow-8.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow [this](https://idomagor.medium.com/short-and-hopefully-simple-guide-to-install-python-libraries-to-a-offline-station-computer-ad8fd2757921). Obviously you must replace the packages with the ones you need.

> ```
> virtualenv my-new-virtual-env
> cd my-new-virtual-env
> ```
>
> Activate the environment using the commands shown above.
> For our convenience lets create in the root folder of the env a Wheelhouse/Tarhouse folder which will we install all our packages.
>
> (Windows) `mkdir Wheelhouse` and afterwards `cd Wheelhouse`
>
> (Linux) `mkdir Tarhouse` and afterwards `cd Tarhouse`
>
> ```
> pip download virtualenv django numpy 
> pip freeze > requirements.txt
> ```
>
> Take the downloaded .whl/.tar files to an offline station
>
> Make sure you are in the root folder of the virtual envrionment and
> issue the following command in your command line:
>
> ```
> pip install -r requirements.txt --find-links=(Wheelhouse or Tarhouse)
> ```
>
> I just wanted to add up that you can issue the command(if you want
> install single package at a time):
>
> ```
> pip install Wheelhouse/some-package-file.whl (or .tar on linux)
> ```

Comment: This works good sir. Thank you so much..:)

Comment: @Visharma You're welcome! Please mark this answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: OK ,Sorry to post this comment just ran my project package  "pyautogui"  is installed, but pillow which is in wheel file is not installed. On off line machine do we need to create and activate virtual env first (I am trying without creating one)?..Pls help...!!!!

Comment: gives error "could not find version that satisfies the requirement Pillow==8.01

Comment: installning this on windows 10 VM, tried : pip install Pillow===8.01 (didnt work), tried "pip install Pillow****.whl" didnt work...fyi

Comment: problem solved : Needed python 3.7 on the system not 3.9,Thank you